# TFS Build: Create git-tag during build

Tags: git, tfsbuild, git-tag

I am trying tag sources during a build with the build number. To create the tag via command-line is not rocket science, but that prompts me for my login details.

How would I be able to modify my build process to create a git tag just after it got the source from git.

Thanks,
MS